# angular-tree-component json to acceptable format and dynamically create checkbox or radio button

Tags: javascript, json, angular, treeview

I have a treeview using **angular-tree-component** as use of following link [Refernece](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs)

Where the array is in below format:

```
nodes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'root1',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
        { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'root2',
      children: [
        { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'child2.2',
          children: [
            { id: 7, name: 'granchild 2.2.1' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

But I have a `json` nested array in the below format:

```
[
    {
        "name": "root1",
        "subCategory": [
            {
                "name": "child1",
                "childCategory": []
            },
            {
                "name": "child2",
                "childCategory": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "level2",
        "subCategory": [
            {
                "name": "level2.1",
                "childCategory": []
            },
            {
                "name": "level2.2",
                "childCategory": [
                    {
                        "name": "granchild 2.2.1",
                        "type": "checkbox"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My doubts are below:

- How can I convert **json** to required **array** Format which is acceptable by the angular-tree-component
- As you can see the type is checkbox `{"name": "granchild 2.2.1","type": "checkbox"}`. So the grandchild 2.2.1 should be a check box and if it was radio button it should be radio.

Please guide me...

Comment: Your output desired array not contains place where we can put type of childCategory - show can you update it ans showe where `type` shoud be placed?

Answer (score 1):

You can transform json to your array using this code (id=1 at start)

```
a.map(x=> (
  x.id=id,
  id++,   
  x.subCategory.map(y=> (
    y.id=id,
    id++,
    (y.childCategory.length ? y.children=y.childCategory : 0),
    y.childCategory.map(z=> (z.id=id, id++)),
    delete y.childCategory
  )),
  (x.subCategory.length ? x.children=x.subCategory : 0),
  delete x.subCategory
));
```

```js
let a=[
    {
        "name": "root1",
        "subCategory": [
            {
                "name": "child1",
                "childCategory": []
            },
            {
                "name": "child2",
                "childCategory": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "level2",
        "subCategory": [
            {
                "name": "level2.1",
                "childCategory": []
            },
            {
                "name": "level2.2",
                "childCategory": [
                    {
                        "name": "granchild 2.2.1",
                        "type": "checkbox"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

let id=1;

a.map(x=> (
  x.id=id,
  id++,   
  x.subCategory.map(y=> (
    y.id=id,
    id++,
    (y.childCategory.length ? y.children=y.childCategory : 0),
    y.childCategory.map(z=> (z.id=id, id++)),
    delete y.childCategory
  )),
  (x.subCategory.length ? x.children=x.subCategory : 0),
  delete x.subCategory
));


console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. Any idea about second part? dynamically creating checkbox or radio button in angular-tree-component? Please check it help me bro. Will mark once you can help me on it.